# how to apply nongreedy ruby regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

Given the possible input strings "foobar-xyz" and "foobar-xyz-abc-def"

How do I match the string "foobar-x" (eg 'from beginning until and including the FIRST character after the first hyphen')?

I expected `/(.*-.?)(.*)/` or `/(.*-.{1}?)(.*)/` to work, but both of them match up to the first character after the LAST hyphen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a cap on your greedy matching using `?`:

```
/(.*?-.?)(.*)/
    ^--- here and make it non-greedy
```